# case statement is showing error invalid column name

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Tnew and has column named weekday, I am executing below simple query but "Invalid column name 'Thursday'" and similarly for each dayname is appearing as error.
Pls support why it is showing error, although when i just run query without case it is working fine.

```
select *, 
   case 
       when weekday = "Thursday" then 1
       when weekday = "Wednesday" then 2
       when weekday = "Tuesday" then 3
       when weekday = "Monday" then 4
       when weekday = "Friday" then 5
       when weekday = "Saturday" then 6
   else 7
   end as col
from Tnew
```

Comment: The answer given is correct but just use single quotes for string literals. Don't mess around with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` or you will find product features (like filtered indexes or XML methods) don't work for you

Answer (score 4):

What is the value for the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` setting ? 
To view the current setting for this setting, run the following query:

```
DECLARE @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER VARCHAR(3) = 'OFF';
IF ( (256 & @@OPTIONS) = 256 ) 
BEGIN
    SET @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER = 'ON';
END

SELECT @QUOTED_IDENTIFIER AS QUOTED_IDENTIFIER;
```

If you have `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` then `"` (double quotation mark ) can be used as string delimiter. (It's `NOT` recommended to have this setting `OFF`)

The recommended solution , is to use `'` (single quotation mark)
instead of `"` (double quotation mark).

`'` =Single quotation mark is used to specify a string value, to delimit a string value.(regardless of Quoted setting)

`"` = Double quotation mark, is depending of a SET Setting (`SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) more info

When `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` Strings inside double quotation marks are treated as object.
When `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF` Strings inside double quotation marks are treated as string values.

```
select *, 
   case 
       when weekday = 'Thursday' then 1
       when weekday = 'Wednesday' then 2
       when weekday = 'Tuesday' then 3
       when weekday = 'Monday' then 4
       when weekday = 'Friday' then 5
       when weekday = 'Saturday' then 6
   else 7
   end as col
from Tnew;
```

output:

| weekday | col |
| --- | --- |
| Thursday | 1 |

Also, this works:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF; 
select *, 
   case 
       when weekday = "Thursday" then 1
       when weekday = "Wednesday" then 2
       when weekday = "Tuesday" then 3
       when weekday = "Monday" then 4
       when weekday = "Friday" then 5
       when weekday = "Saturday" then 6
   else 7
   end as col
from Tnew;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wWY6K90l)

Comment: Thanks a lot you all, it works now

Comment: @user514348, with welcome!